# Netbeans and C, peculiar bug

Tags: c, netbeans

I am writing something in C using Netbeans 6.9.1 (its a requirement) and I stumbled upon a peculiar bug. When I try to run this code from Netbeans:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "company_description.h"


company_description read_company_description() {
    char file_name[FILE_NAME_BUFFER_SIZE];
    FILE *company_description_file;
    company_description cd;


    printf("Please enter the name of the file containing the "
            "company's description: \n");
    scanf("%50s", file_name);


    company_description_file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if(company_description_file != NULL) {
        printf("file is not null\n");
    }
    fscanf(company_description_file, "%s%s%s%s%s%s", cd.company_name,
        cd.name_file_deliveries_info, cd.name_file_industrial_park,
        cd.name_file_places, cd.name_file_roads, cd.name_file_vans_info);
    return cd;
}
```

I get this output:

```
Please enter the name of the file containing the company's description: 
name_file.txt
Segmentation fault
Press [Enter] to close the terminal ...
```

Ok I say to myself, from my point of vie there is nothing wrong with this code and I go to
~/path/to/NetbeansProject/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86 and try to run the executable from there and it works. I forgot to mention that the file that should be read is in that same folder, exactly where the executable is. Now there might be a mistake on my side but I don't see it so any thoughts about this would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Your working directory is probably incorrect - when you run from Netbeans, the working directory is not necessarily the same as where the executable resides.

Comment: @Birryree, I think you are right, post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to why it doesn't run in Netbeans: working directory is probably incorrect - when you run from Netbeans, the working directory is not necessarily the same as where the executable resides.

I do not have Netbeans installed, but you can set the working directory (what directory the system thinks the executable was executed in) in your project's settings.

I also agree with aschelper's answer - if you don't get a valid `FILE *` back you don't want to continue running that file code.

Comment: Thank you @birryree, that's the solution and as I pointed in the previous comments I am aware of the missing else in the file handling :).

Answer (score 1):

Your code will probably crash if `fopen` fails.  Sure, you have a check for whether `company_description_file != NULL`, but then if it is null you go ahead and pass it to `fscanf` anyway (rather than `exit()`ing or returning early or something).  Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, though I don't think that is the problem because when I invoke the code from the command line it works, I think that @birryree is right, so I just have to figure how to change the current working directory of this bloody thing. Thanks anyway man :).

Answer (score 0):

Don't blame the compiler/IDE, the bug is in your code :)

```
company_description_file = fopen(file_name, "r");
if(company_description_file != NULL) {
    printf("file is not null\n");
}
fscanf(...
```

There is an else missing that will cope with the situation when the file is not found. Right now you pass a NULL pointer to fscanf which causes the crash. Your program cannot find the file most probably because NetBeans sets the working directory somewhere else. Make sure you set the correct working directory or copy the input file to the proper location.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it, I agree with you, though I just posted it like this (quick and dirty) because the file I give both in Netbeans and in the command line is the same and in the former case it doesn't work and in the latter it does. Anyway thanks again.